# Filter images in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, image, filter

I am writing VBA code to filter images. The goal is to write a macro to lock in the photos so they do not move when I need to filter the other columns. This is the code that I have so far. I need help doing this in VBA. Thanks.

```
Sub getpic()

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableAnimations = False

Dim url_column As Range
Dim image_column As Range

Dim rngColSelect As String

rngColSelect = ActiveCell.Column

Set url_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns("A")
Set image_column = Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Columns(Col_Letter(ActiveCell.Column))

Dim pic As Shape

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To url_column.Cells.Count
    If Not IsError(Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column))) Then
        
        If Left(Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column)), 4) = "http" Then

        Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column)).Select
        Set pic = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column)).Value _
                          , msoFalse, msoTrue, Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column)).Left, Range(Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column), Cells(i, ActiveCell.Column)).Top, -1, -1)

        pic.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        pic.Height = 115
        pic.Placement = xlMoveAnSize
                
        Rows(i).RowHeight = 120
        Columns(Col_Letter(ActiveCell.Column)).ColumnWidth = 50

        End If
    End If

Next

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableAnimations = True

MsgBox "Process complete!", vbOKOnly, "Completed"


End Sub
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

Comment: What's the specific problem you're having with that code?

Comment: FYI you have `xlMoveAnSize` which should be `xlMoveAndSize`

Comment: And `Columns(Col_Letter(ActiveCell.Column))` is the same as `Columns(ActiveCell.Column)` since `Columns()` accepts either a string column label or numeric column index